# Problem With Setting Environment Variables Correctly In Windows 10, and Module Not Found Error

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

I am having problems with setting environment variables in Windows 10. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Also in case anyone asks, I am using the latest version of Python.

I pulled the code from [this github](https://github.com/mdaus/nitro) to test out the project.

Whenever I try to run a .py file in the nitro project that imports the nitf module on the cmd like so `python [any .py file name].py` , I get a Module Not found error stating that the nitf module does not exist.

In order to solve this problem, I checked [the issues page](https://github.com/mdaus/nitro/issues/132) where someone had a problem similar to mine. The page emphasized setting up environment variables to fix the issue.

This is how I have set up the NITF_PLUGIN_PATH, the PYTHONPATH, and the System Variable Path according to [this youtube video I found online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2q_b4ugPWk). (Images are below, the red blocks out my name):

[The error I keep getting with the module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AMzq.png)

[The path I added for the NITF_PLUGIN_PATH as per issues page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FZgV.png)

[The path I added for PYTHONPATH as per video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frSjt.png)

[The path I added for System Variable Path as per video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIDzK.png)

But even after I set the variables, and restarting the cmd, I keep seeing that the nitf module does not exist. I've tried multiple different pathways for the variables, but those don't work either. Now I'm at a loss. Any advice on what to do, or where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Don't post images and esp. links to images.  Put the information in the question text itself so it is a standalone issue that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: pip install nitf

Comment: when I try "pip install nitf" it doesn't work - I see the message "No matching distribution found for nitf"